# java does not exist but java version is thrown up

Tags: command-line

while installing jstock using terminal when jstock.sh is executed I get the error 'bin/java  does not exist' but java -version gives me version. Please suggest.

```
navjeet@navjeet-Lenovo-G50-80:/opt/jstock$ ./jstock.sh
Warning: /bin/java does not exist
navjeet@navjeet-Lenovo-G50-80:/opt/jstock$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-0ubuntu4~16.04.1-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
navjeet@navjeet-Lenovo-G50-80:/opt/jstock$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jstock` is doing something dumb there and looking for java in `/bin/java` which is not where it would be located on almost any system, Ubuntu included. Here is a quick workaround:

First find out where Java really is:

```
which java
```

On my system this is `/usr/bin/java` which makes sense. Next we create a symbolic link to make `/bin/java` point to `/usr/bin/java`

```
ln -s /usr/bin/java /bin/java
```

Now `jstock` should be able to find Java.

Comment: Mine is also /usr/bin/java . shall make the link and let you know.

Comment: It worked ! :) ...i wanna add a smiley 'coz that's what i'm doing smiling )...